# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$cphMain$txCourseDescription="...ace="'MS Sans Serif&#...")

Tags: javascript, vb.net

My screen has a Telrik rad popup which populate on a button `click(btnCourseDescription)`. I have taken a label to show html formated data and a textbox to work with code behind file. when I click on `btnCourseDescription`; Telrik's popup opens and and after submit it shows data on label and assign value to textbox using Javascript ... Here is my Javascript code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function clientShow(sender, eventArgs)
        {
            //$find();
            var txtInput = document.getElementById("<%=lbCourseDescription.ClientID%>");
            sender.argument = txtInput.innerHTML;
        }

        function clientClose(sender, args)
        {
            if (args.get_argument() != null)
            {
                var lbInput = document.getElementById("<%=lbCourseDescription.ClientID%>");
                var txtInput = document.getElementById("<%=txCourseDescription.ClientID%>");
                lbInput.innerHTML = args.get_argument();
                txtInput.value = args.get_argument.htmlEncode();

            }
        }    
</script>
```

Now when I click on `btnCourseDescription` and and assign value using popup data submits successfully but when I want to update any other field means I am not updating HTML formatted data, HARDERROR occurs:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$cphMain$txCourseDescription="...ace="'MS Sans Serif&#...").

Please suggest me what should I do?

Comment: Have you checked [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)?

Comment: Yes, I have viewed this but I doesn't help me.